# nginx: does it generate conflicts if any of the dynamic modules are different?

Tags: nginx, cache

I have an instance on AWS running Ubuntu 22.04 on which I installed nginx and cloned the instance to build the ngx_purgue_cache module.

This is my current nginx output

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-zctdR4/nginx-1.18.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-zctdR4/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module
```

When I tried to compile nginx with the purgue_cache module I realized that there was an error (not found) with the following module:

```
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-zctdR4/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2
```

To solve it I had to recompile geoIp as a new dynamic module.
which resulted in the following 2 modules:

```
ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so
ngx_http_geoip2_module.so
```

My question is if I just copy the ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so module to my production instance which contains another version of the geoip module, will I have any problems?

Comment: We don't know. How hard would it be to test?

Comment: There is no problem with it if you compile all modules with `--with-compat` flag and against the same NGINX version. But compilation of any software on production (or compiling any software in general for production) is highly discouraged. See [Where compilation went wrong…](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/where-compilation-went-wrong)